# DBT - snowflake - pre_hook and select query to run within a single transaction?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have a snowflake table which is already clustered and has some shares along with comments on columns added.

For subsequent refreshes, I want to run an insert overwrite into table instead of create or replace table as so as to preserve the schema and shares.

In dbt implementation, I used `materialized: incremental` and `incremental_strategy: append` for the model along with a pre-hook sql config `"pre-hook": "TRUNCATE {{ this }}"`.

I want to ensure that pre_hook and select statement to run within a single transaction. If not, my model could have 0 entries if my insert into command fails for some reason. How to ensure that this runs in a single transaction?

Comment: Shouldn't you use the sql_header parameter? (https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/sql_header). SQL in a sql_header is run in the same query.

Answer (score 1):

In dbt, hooks and model SQL are executed within the same transaction by default. However, Snowflake treats each statement outside an explicit transaction as if it is inside its own implicit single-statement transaction. To ensure that the pre_hook and select statement in your dbt model run within a single transaction, you can wrap them in explicit transaction commands.

you can use a dbt macro to combine the pre_hook and select statement into a single transaction.

```
{% macro truncate_and_insert() %}
    {% set sql -%}
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        TRUNCATE {{ this }};
        INSERT INTO {{ this }} SELECT * FROM {{ source('source_table') }};
        COMMIT;
    {%- endset %}

    {% do run_query(sql) %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Then in your model yaml file:

```yaml
models:
  <resource-path>:
    +pre-hook: "{{ truncate_and_insert() }}"
```

Comment: If this is written as a pre_hook will there be any materialization in addition to the query mentioned in ```sql``` ?

Comment: In dbt, hooks and model SQL are executed within the same transaction by default. However, the execution of a pre-hook doesn't affect the materialization of the model itself. In your case, running the pre-hook macro to truncate and insert data doesn't affect the materialization of the model.

Comment: The materialization will still be determined by what you've specified in your model or dbt_project.yml file. For example, if you've set the materialization of your model to be table, dbt will create a new table in the database for your model, regardless of the pre-hook. The pre-hook will simply run before the table creation.